# Issues with posting images and maintaining other buttons on the view

Tags: xcode, swiftui

this is my first post on here so forgive me if I am not descriptive enough or am missing something. I will attach my code at the end of this. So what I have happening is 5 'addPhoto' buttons being presented on the screen. When the first image is selected the other buttons disappear. I want the user to be able to select up to 5 total images and in order for them to do that they need the other buttons to be accesable. I want the selected image to take the place of the button that they clicked on to access the image picker and remain there until they hit the 'Post Item' which will be implemented at the end of the screen when they fill in all the necessary information. Any suggestions on how to implement this are appreciated. I am relatively new to coding so I appreciate the assistance. Thanks all in advance.

```
struct PostItemView: View {
    @State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @State var postImage: Image?
    @State var description = ""
    @State var imagePickerPresented = false


    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                HStack {
                    CircularProfileImageView(size: .medium)
                    Text("User Name")
                        .font(.system(size: 18,weight: .semibold))
                }.padding(.top,30)
                    .padding()

                Spacer()

                Text("Add Photos (max. of 5)")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.system(size: 18,weight: .semibold))

                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack{
                        if postImage == nil {
                            Button(action: {imagePickerPresented.toggle()}, label: {
                                AddPhotoButton()
                            }).sheet(isPresented: $imagePickerPresented, onDismiss: loadImage,content: {
                                ImagePicker(image: $selectedImage)
                            })


                            Button(action: {imagePickerPresented.toggle()}, label: {
                                AddPhotoButton()
                            }).sheet(isPresented: $imagePickerPresented, onDismiss: loadImage,content: {
                                ImagePicker(image: $selectedImage)
                            })

                            Button(action: {imagePickerPresented.toggle()}, label: {
                                AddPhotoButton()
                            }).sheet(isPresented: $imagePickerPresented, onDismiss: loadImage,content: {
                                ImagePicker(image: $selectedImage)
                            })

                            Button(action: {imagePickerPresented.toggle()}, label: {
                                AddPhotoButton()
                            }).sheet(isPresented: $imagePickerPresented, onDismiss: loadImage,content: {
                                ImagePicker(image: $selectedImage)
                            })

                            Button(action: {imagePickerPresented.toggle()}, label: {
                                AddPhotoButton()
                            }).sheet(isPresented: $imagePickerPresented, onDismiss: loadImage,content: {
                                ImagePicker(image: $selectedImage)
                            })

                        } else if let image = postImage {
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 120,height: 120)
                                .clipped()

                        }
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding(4)
                }

                Spacer()

                Text("Give us some details:")
                    .font(.system(size: 18,weight: .semibold))
                    .padding()

                TextField("Enter your information", text: $description)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()

                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Post my Item")
                })
                .font(.system(size: 20,weight: .semibold))
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .foregroundColor(.white)


            }
            .navigationTitle("Post Item")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

extension PostItemView {
    func loadImage() {
        guard let selectedImage = selectedImage else { return }
        postImage = Image(uiImage: selectedImage)
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my ImagePicker:

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
@Binding var image: UIImage?
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    return picker
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    let parent: ImagePicker
    
    init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        self.parent.image = image
        self.parent.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

}

I have tried to implement the multiple buttons but I feel like that is inefficient and could be done a different way. Also, I think the solution could come using arrays but I am not really strong with arrays yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is the way you are trying to display the image at the buttons position. At the moment you are replacing all the buttons with the image first selected. If you want to replace the button with an image you would need to put the if clause you have right now around each individual button. If you want to allow the user to change an image that they selected you should use your AddPhotoButton View and replace the normal appearance with the image. In general I would recommend having a predetermined size for the buttons and not to let them change dynamically between having images assigned to them since the UI could shift around a lot otherwise.
The second problem is that you assign postImage a value as soon as an image is selected for one of the buttons. This causes you to jump into the second part of your if statement thus only displaying the selected image. This is because you call the loadImage function every time the sheet closes.
A problem that you are gonna run into is that you can't use the same variable for each of the buttons. An array probably would be the best way to store the images. A decent tutorial for arrays can be found here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0/6/arrays
I would also use a ForEach loop to display the buttons. It's gonna make the code easier to read less time consuming to write, edit and just clean things up a bit. A short tutorial can be found here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach and a more comprehensive one here https://www.swiftyplace.com/blog/swiftui-foreach-more-than-just-loops-in-swift

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my original question to include the ImagePicker code.

Comment: @PrairieNomad edited the answer to hopefully help you to get the program working as intended